# Editing any amount of text causes hang

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

On https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database, if I edit the first example, delete all the existing text, type "a", and wait for a moment, the page becomes unresponsive for a few seconds. Any significant amount of text makes for a several-minute wait.

Encountered in both Chrome 51 and 52.